# anchor tags are not working after rewrite url logic is implemented in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, anchor

we have successfully implemented rewriting logic using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter. However anchor tags are not working. what to do?

before url rewriting

```
www.mysite.com/productdetail.aspx?pid=10&catid=20

www.mysite.com/productdetail.aspx?pid=10&catid=20#contact
```

after rewrite following is working

```
www.mysite.com/product/10/20/apple-iphone-4-black
```

but this is not working

```
www.mysite.com/product/10/20/apple-iphone-4-black#contact
```

when we hit anchor tag link on my actual aspx page, it goes to our index page instead and

url becomes like this

```
www.mysite.com/#contact
```